# Limit of $b_n$ when $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=l$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I have the following problem.

I have to find the limit of $b_n = \frac{a_n}{n}$, where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=l$

**My approach:**

I express $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$, i.e.
$a_n=nb_n$ and $a_{n+1}=(n+1)b_n$

We look at the difference: $a_{n+1}-a_n=(n+1)b_{n+1}-nb_n$

Assuming that $b_n$ converges to a real number m, we see that:

$l=(n+1)m-nm$, from where I conclude that $m=l$.

What I'm left with is proving that $b_n$ is convergent which I'm not sure how to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer section does not make sense. Take for instance $a_n = n$ so that $l = 1$, and $b_n = 1 \ne e$.

Comment: Still, Is my solution correct?

Comment: I've added an edit changing the question to proof verification type.

Comment: You still have to prove that $(b_n)_n$ is convergent.

Comment: the first line of your approach should say "[...] and $a_{n+1}=(n+1)b_{n+1}$".

Comment: Your solution has serious problems. The equation $l=(n+1)m-nm$ does not make sense here.

Comment: The problem is a direct corollary of Cesaro-Stolz Theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ParamanandSingh suggested, from [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) 
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(n+1)-n} \rightarrow l, n \rightarrow \infty$$
where $\{n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotone and divergent, then 
$$\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow l, n \rightarrow \infty$$