# Limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt[k] {k} }{n}= 1$

Tags: limits, radicals

I would like to prove that:

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt[k] {k} }{n}= 1$$

I thought to write $\sqrt[k] {k} = e^{\frac{\ln({k})}{k}}$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: for any $\varepsilon>0$, you have $\sqrt[k]{k}<1+\varepsilon$ for $k\geq n_0$ for some $n_0$.

Comment: The key is that $\sqrt[k]{k}\to1$ as $k\to\infty$

Comment: for any $\epsilon >0$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt[k] {k} }{n} \le \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{ n(1+\epsilon) }{n}= 1+ \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) or a version of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439095/limit-of-b-n-when-b-n-fraca-nn-and-lim-limits-n-to-inftya-n1-a/).

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \sqrt[k] {k} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt[k] {k}  }{n+1 - n}=
 \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt[n+1] {n+1}  =1$$